# Ansible nodes IPs as the one string

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I use Vagrant with Ansible. In my playbook I have the following variable:

```
seeds: '192.168.56.11,192.168.56.12'
```

`192.168.56.11` and `192.168.56.12` here are IP addresses of multi-machine Vagrant configuration.

Can I do my configuration more flexible using Ansible i.e. can Ansible compose this string programmatically for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jinja2 to template out your variable from other variables.

So if we have a list of things like this:

```
seeds:
 - 192.168.56.11
 - 192.168.56.12
```

We can turn that into a comma delimited string by [looping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures) through it with something like this:

```
seeds_string: '{% for seed in seeds %} {{ seed }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}'
```

As for getting the IP addresses of hosts in your inventory we can access facts about other hosts than the one being configured by using [the `groups` and `hostvars` magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

So to get the IP addresses of all hosts in the inventory we could use something like:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Combining this together we can then do something like this:

```
seeds: '{% for host in groups['all'] %} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just checked it in my project, it works like a charm.